# Scaled pixmap in QLabel looks bad

Tags: c++, image, qt, qt5, qlabel

So I try to load up a raw image file inside Qt which works perfectly fine with QtRaw/libraw. What I get is a QImage which is displayed inside a QLabel like this:

```
    QImageReader reader("/Users/dublin/Pictures/Ich/IMG_5098.CR2");
    QImage raw = reader.read();

    displayLbl->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(raw).scaled(1024, 768, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
    layout->addWidget(displayLbl);
    displayLbl->show();
```

The problem here is that the image looks "pixelated" and very bad. This does not even happen with CR2/Raw files, also if I try it with JPEGs. Take a look here:

[image: bad1]

and if we zoom in a little more:

[image: reallybad]

How can I display the image in the highest possible quality?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Qt scaller is not intended to do that. Photoshop does !You should use an ofline process or get a correct image scaler source code I imagine bilinear filtering will not do the job.

Comment: @Gold does not really make sense to me, because the Qt ImageViewer example also works even if I choose something like "Fit to Window". I just want to fit it to the maximum label size. It is something like a preview image before you can simply edit/organize it.

Comment: Well in order to prevent jagged edges when zooming and resizing ( mathematical resampling ) I personaly  use a 15 pass 2D floating point algorithm as when I edit textures for a video game. I don't remember it's name but there are dozen of them. This task is really less obvious than one may think but that is the way ;-)

Comment: @Gold no any other possible way? I just simply try to display an image in the best quality. I even don‘t need zooming at this point. But the jagged edges can even be seen when just scaling

Comment: I looked at the description  'SmoothTransformation : The resulting image is transformed using bilinear filtering.'  You are limited to this Quality when using this API. For better results you should use something more advanced either using third parties.

Comment: In fact image resizing is a direct application of shanon's theory, like music, therefore it is much more complicated than it may seems at first glance. Downsizing an image requires that you process along X then Y having multiple filtered representation layers of high/low frequency then wisely blending them in order to avoid for low noises artefacts inducing to much jagged edges. That's the job of photoshopm but take a look at this one 'https://github.com/avaneev/avir'

Comment: @Gold I understand but I think that would be a little to overkill for my little application. I‘m going try to realize this with a ScrollArea which is going to be fixed. Phototonic (https://github.com/oferkv/phototonic) is using similar approaches in their preview image. And it works just as I would expect. Thanks for clearing up anyways.

Comment: @Gold so it works: https://github.com/dublin19/rdi/commit/351a2d2d0d54113ddd0453be341e87261f296005